# "Error uncleared PCH FIFO underrun on transcoder A" during boot centos 7 on toshiba

Tags: linux, centos, boot

I have toshiba Satelite model (C50 1001C model number) laptop. When I start it is giving

```
1.643361 [drm:cpt_serr_int_handler] *ERROR*  uncleared PCH FIFO underrun on transcoder A
1.643363 [drm cpt_serr_int_handler] *ERROR* pch transcoder a fifo underrun
```

In this laptop, I have an important installation and source code, I just searched but I did not get any correct solution.

Comment: See this post here on StackExchange: https://askubuntu.com/questions/840496/startup-error-uncleared-pch-fifo-underrun-on-pch-transcoder

Answer (score 1):

Those messages are coming from buggy intel i915 driver for video adapter. There is nothing you can do about them (except for sending them as bugreports to linux upstream).

They have nothing to do with filesystem.

PCH is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub, as you can see, it's not related to filesystems in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Linux Mint. I've solved it using:
`fsck -f /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root`

`fsck` is a tool to scan your file system and fix problems. If you aren't using Mint but Centos, you might need to adapt it to scan your own root partition. `vg-root` is the [equivalent](https://askubuntu.com/a/593778) of `/dev/sdaN`.
E.g. see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually) for a simmilar problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my [Shuttle DS437](https://global.shuttle.com/main/productsDetail?productId=1745), similar error messages were the last lines visible during boot.

My fault was to assume that the boot process stopped there. And that these lines were the symptom of something substantial. Instead, booting continued invisible in the background successfully. So the solution was to ignore the messages and just connect via other means; in my case SSH.